# Advice needed... Javascript OOP/namespacing

Tags: javascript, namespaces, object

right now i am at a point where i feel that i need to improve my javascript skills because i already see that what i want to realize will get quite complex. I've iterrated over the same fragment of code now 4 times and i am still not sure if it's the best way.

**The task:**
A user of a webpage can add different forms to a webpage which i call modules. Each form provides different user inputs and needs to be handled differently. Forms/Modules of the same type can be added to the list of forms as the user likes.

**My current solution:**
To make the code more readable and seperate functions i use namespaced objects. The first object holds general tasks and refers to the individual forms via a map which holds several arrays where each contains the **id of a form** and the **reference to the object** which holds all  the functions which need to be performed especially for that kind of form.

---

The structure looks more or less similar to this:

```
var module_handler = {

    _map  : [],    /* Map {reference_to_obj, id} */

    init: function(){            
        var module = example_module; /* Predefined for this example */
        this.create(module);
    },

    create: function(module) {
        //Store reference to obj id in map
        this._map.push([module,id = this.createID()]);
        module.create(id);
    },

    createID: function(id) {
        //Recursive function to find an available id
    },

    remove: function(id) {

        //Remove from map
        var idx = this._map.indexOf(id);
        if(idx!=-1) this._map.splice(idx, 1);

        //Remove from DOM
        $('#'+id+'').remove();
    }
}

var example_module = {

    create: function(id) {
        //Insert html
        $('#'+id+' > .module_edit_inner').replaceWith("<some html>");
    }
}
```

---

**Now comes my question ;-)**
Is the idea with the map needed?

I mean: Isn't there something  more elegant like:

var moduleXYZ = new example_module(id)

which copies the object and refers only to that form.... Something more logical and making speed improvements?? **The main issue is that right now i need to traverse the DOM each time if i call for example "example_module.create()** or later on any other function. With this structure i cant refer to the form like with something like "this"???

---

Do you see any improvements at this point??? This would help me very much!!! Really i am just scared to go the wrong way now looking at all the stuff i will put on top of this ;-)

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for prototype:

=========

```
function exampleModule(id)
{
    this.id = id;
}


exampleModule.prototype.create = function()
{

}
```

=========

```
var module1 = new exampleModule(123);
module1.create();

var module2 = new exampleModule(456);
module2.create();
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks... i think this is the right way. Now i have to figure out how to apply this to the structure i already have ;-)

Comment: I'd recommend separating each class out into a separate JS file.  Name it the name of the class.  At this point, you're getting pretty close to Java/OOP.  You just need to be careful with preserving "this".  The Prototype JS library is very useful for this type of OOP JS programming.